# Do I need to initialize the values of a structure before I use them?

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to create a dynamic array of a struct `wordStruct` that holds a string and the number of times it occurs in a text file:

```
typedef struct wordStruct{
  char word[50];
  int count = 0;
}wordStruct;
```

I will get the number I need from reading the number of words in the file, let's call it `wordCount`.

```
struct wordStruct *wordList;
wordList = (wordStruct *)malloc(wordCount * sizeof(wordStruct));
```

Is this the correct way to allocate the memory for `struct` array?  Would `calloc()` be a better option?

```
int wordListIndex = 0;
char[50] inWord; // No word will be more than 49 characters + null terminator
for (i = 0; i < wordCount; i++){
  fscanf(data, "%s", inWord);
  for (j = 0; j < wordCount; j++){
    if (strcmp(wordList[j].word, inWord) == 0){
      wordList[j].count++;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (j == wordCount){
  strcpy(wordList[wordListIndex].word, inWord)
  wordListIndex++;
  }
```

I know that this probably isn't the most efficient code, but do I have the right idea?  Can I use the `strcmp()` method even though there may not be any data in those array locations?  I'm new to structs and I'm not sure what I can and cannot do.

Thanks.

Comment: if you're typedef'ing it, why are you using struct to declare a wordStruct?

Comment: Your first struct declaration is not C code. What is it doing here? The rest of the code is also full of weird declarations. `char[50] inWord;` - what is it?

Comment: I'm new structs and I'm not sure on the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `malloc`, you need to initialize the array (e.g., using `memset`). If you use `calloc`, the array is initialized to 0 for you.

Once the array is initialized, you can use `strcmp` on it, because setting it to 0 makes all the words be zero-length (empty) strings. Before initializing it, you must not use `strcmp`.

(I'm assuming the weird `char[50] varname` instead of `char varname[50]` are typos in your SO question, else this wouldn't compile. I'm also ignoring the buffer overflow in `fscanf` and `strcpy`… well, technically, I guess I'm not. And the lack of error handling.)

Comment: ok, ill switch it to calloc() then. whats the buffer overflow for fscanf?

Comment: @MichaelSchilling: The one you're assuming will never happen—a word longer than 49 characters. You can tell `fscanf` that maximum length by using `%49s`.

Answer (score 0):

The nested for loop should use wordListIndex for the boundary condition and the last if block should be taken out of the inner for loop. The condition should should be

```
if (j == wordListIndex){
  strcpy(wordList[wordListIndex].word, inWord)
  wordListIndex++;
}
```

Comment: I just realized that that shouldn't be int the second for loop, but in the second. Fixing now.